# C# - I know I can do this in LINQ, but I can't get it to work

Tags: c#, linq

I got a list of RegionGroup objects with two properties: an int "number" and a list<> of "Regions".

I need to output a distribution of number of Region objects combined for each number.
For example, given:

[Region 1] - number: 1 - list<> has 5 members

[Region 2] - number: 3 - list<> has 2 members

[Region 3] - number: 4 - list<> has 9 members

[Region 4] - number: 1 - list<> has 5 members

[Region 5] - number: 3 - list<> has 4 members

I need to get something like:

number:1 - total 10 members

number:3 - total 6 members

number:4 - total 9 members

I've been messing around with various tutorials, and I think I need to use groups, but I couldn't quite get anything working.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this similar question may help:

[Linq Query with SUM and ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820552/linq-query-with-sum-and-order-by)

or this one

[C# List<> GroupBy 2 Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363655/c-list-groupby-2-values)

Comment: looked at the first one and arrived at a working solution. thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the region number and then get the total number of members in the lists.

How about something like this (untested):

```
var regionCounts = from region in RegionGroups
                   group region by region.number into g
                   select new {number = g.Key, 
                               regions = g.Sum(r=>r.Regions.Count)};
```